# Send email with Nodemailer in Locallhost (ReferenceError: require is not defined)

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I want to send the data of this form with Nodemailer. But when I click the `enviar` button in the browser (locallhost) on the console I get the following error:`ReferenceError: require is not defined`. My node version is `v7.9.0`.

I should clarify that when I run app.js from the terminal (without the function) `function send () {}` if it sends the mail.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo4</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Formulario</h1>
        <select>
            <option>Vida</option>
            <option>Hogar</option>
            <option>Auto</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="email" value="email">
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="enviar()">
        
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```js
function enviar(){

    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '****@gmail.com',
            pass: '******'
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"****" <****@gmail.com>',
        to: '****@***.com',
        subject: 'Lorem ipsum',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum',
        html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    });
    
};
```

**app.js** Without the function `function enviar(){}` Tested from the terminal if you send the mail.

```js
    var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: '****@gmail.com',
            pass: '******'
        }
    });

    let mailOptions = {
        from: '"****" <****@gmail.com>',
        to: '****@***.com',
        subject: 'Lorem ipsum',
        text: 'Lorem ipsum',
        html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    });
```

Comment: Node runs serverside, not in the browser. You will need to connect your client and server apps, probably with AJAX calls. Otherwise, you're exposing your login credentials to anyone who accesses your site

Comment: @user3080953 then how can I send the form the mail? Or what other options can I implement?

Comment: Look up how to create a server in node and start there

Comment: @user3080953 Thank you for clarifying the concepts I will search, if you know of any related tutorial you can follow it would be great